# DropdownList selected value not selected

Tags: model-view-controller

I have two entities: Departments and department type.
In the Index view of department I show a list of department and when click in a button a Modal opens and show the details of the department.

In this modal the department that has a department type, is showed with a dropdownlist. I am not able to get this dropdownlist selected with the value I have set into the controller.

Here is the code, is a sample code of what I am trying to do.
Model:

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DepartmentType DepartmentType { get; set; }
    public SelectList DepTypeSelectList { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentType
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DepartmentType> DepartmentType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = new List<Department>();
    list.Add(new Department{ DepartmentId = 1, Name = "Department 1", DepartmentType = new DepartmentType{ TypeId = 2, Description = "Type 2"}});
    var deptList = new List<DepartmentType>
    {
        new DepartmentType {TypeId = 1, Description = "Type Desc 1"},
        new DepartmentType {TypeId = 2, Description = "Type Desc 2"}
    };
    var selectList = new SelectList(deptList, "TypeId", "Description", 2);
    list[0].DepTypeSelectList = selectList;
    ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(deptList, "TypeId", "Description");
    return View(list);
}
```

Index View for the department:

```
@model IEnumerable<ValidationTest.Models.Department>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @{
                    var divName = "#myModal" + item.DepartmentType.TypeId;
                }
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="@divName">Open Modal</button>
                @Html.Partial("_DepartmentType", item)

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Partial View Department Type:

```
@model ValidationTest.Models.Department

@{
    var divName = "myModal" + Model.DepartmentType.TypeId;
}

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="@divName" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Department Type</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Type Id: @Model.DepartmentType.TypeId</p>
                <p>Description: @Model.DepartmentType.Description</p>
                <p>
                    @Html.DropDownList("TypeId", Model.DepTypeSelectList, "-- Select Type --", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any Help?
Thanks

Comment: Please, update your post with a specific question.

Comment: The question is specific, as it says: why I am not able to get the dropdownlist selected. Please check the controller code: var selectList = new SelectList(deptList, "TypeId", "Description", 2);
I am passing a select list with a selected Item and when I open the model the combo is not selected. In addition I posted a very simple and easy code.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection. Nor can you use a partial (you need to use an `EditorTemplate`), but why are you creating multiple forms - you can only post back one - and what is the controller method signature that your posting back to. And your dropdownlist is binding to a proeprty named `TypeId` which does not exist (although you do have one named `DepartmentType.TypeId`).

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved my problem with this code:

Model:

```
    public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentTypeId { get; set; }
        public DepartmentType DepartmentType { get; set; }

        //Select list stuf
        public string SlectedValue { get; set; } //DropDownList selected values
        public List DepTypeSelectList { get; set; } // CountryList 
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List items = new List();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Type 1", Value = "1" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Type 2", Value = "2" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Type 3", Value = "3" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Type 4", Value = "4" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Type 5", Value = "5" });

        var list = new List
        {
            new Department
            {
                DepartmentId = 1,
                Name = "Department 1",
                DepartmentTypeId = 2,
                DepartmentType = new DepartmentType {TypeId = 2, Description = "Type 2"},
                SlectedValue = "2",
                DepTypeSelectList = items
            },
            new Department
            {
                DepartmentId = 2,
                Name = "Department 2",
                DepartmentTypeId = 1,
                DepartmentType = new DepartmentType {TypeId = 1, Description = "Type 1"},
                SlectedValue = "1",
                DepTypeSelectList = items
            },
            new Department
            {
                DepartmentId = 3,
                Name = "Department 3",
                DepartmentTypeId = 2,
                DepartmentType = new DepartmentType {TypeId = 2, Description = "Type 2"},
                SlectedValue = "2",
                DepTypeSelectList = items
            }
        };

        return View(list);
    }
```

View:

```
        @model IEnumerable
    
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    
    
        
            
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            
            
        
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            
                
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                
                
                    @{
                        var divName = "#myModal" + item.DepartmentType.TypeId;
                    }
                    Open Modal
                    @Html.Partial("_DepartmentType", item)

                
            
        }
```

Partial View:

```
    @model ValidationTest.Models.Department
    @{
        var divName = "myModal" + Model.DepartmentType.TypeId;
    }
    
    
        

            
            
                
                    ×
                    Department Type
                
                
                    Type Id: @Model.DepartmentType.TypeId
                    Description: @Model.DepartmentType.Description
                    
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SlectedValue, Model.DepTypeSelectList, "Please select", new { id = "DepartmentTypeId" })
                    
                
                
                    Close
```

All is working fine now.
The reason because I am creating multiple forms is because in the index I have a list of rows (the department list) and when click in one a popup must be opened and you should be able to edit the selected department.

Is true that there are many forms but they don't crash between themselves, and I don't know other way to do this. The customer request was a list in the index with editable popups (modals).

Cheers